# Are permissions checked for running action menu item or opening display menu item with MenuFunction?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a method which calls different MenuItems, depending on parameters:

e.g.

```
new MenuFunction(menuitemActionStr(MenuItemToCall), MenuItemType::Action).run(args);
```

Will it be automatically checked if the current user has permissions to open/run the various menu items?
If not, how can I check by code the privileges of the user/ the needed permissions of the menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it will be automatically checked whether the current user has permissions to open/run menu items.

2) You can use following methods from the `Global` class:

- `boolean hasMenuItemAccess(MenuName name, MenuItemType type)`
- `boolean hasMenuItemSecurityAccess(MenuFunction _menu)`